# Regular expression match multiple substring

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have written a regular expression to test how a string is a logical expression or not. Here is the regular expression:

```
/(.*)(<|>|<=|>=|=|!=)(.*)/
```

And here is the subject which I tested with the expression above:

```
3!=2
```

The `preg_match_all` function in PHP return the following array:

```
[
  [
    "3!=2"
  ],
  [
    null
  ],
  [
    "="
  ],
  [
    "2"
  ]
]
```

I got a wrong logical operator because it's not match only the `=` pattern but also match the `!=` operator. How should I rewrite the regular expression to not match multiple strings in the brackets?

Comment: What do you mean `multiple strings in the brackets`, your regex does nothing with brackets, and your search string has no brackets.

Comment: @kukko, show the expected resulting array

Comment: I expected the following array: `[["3!=2],["3"],["!="],["2"]]`

Comment: @chris85 Excuse me, I mean parenthesis instead of brackets.

Comment: So `3!=2` should be inside parenthesis?

Comment: No, they not need to be in parenthesis. I mean to the parenthesis in the regular expression which contain the logical operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should exclude `<>!` before the operator and `=` after operator. Then, just to shorten, group the operators tighter.

```
([^<>!]*)([<>]=?|!?=)([^=]*)
```

You could also shorten it a bit with this:

```
(\w+)([<>]=?|!?=)(\w+)
```

---

With `<=>`, use

```
([^<>!]*)(<=>|[<>]=?|!?=)([^=>]*)
```

or, better yet in some cases,

```
(\w+)(<=>|[<>]=?|!?=)(\w+)
```

Comment: How could I add the spaceship operator to this expression?

Comment: @kukko Do you mean `<=>`?

Comment: @kukko I haven't found any tight way to do it, just with usual "or" - see the edit.

Comment: The second regular expression won't work for me on the same logical expression.

Comment: @kukko Sorry, I don't understand. With what example does it fail?

Comment: But I edited the first regular epression to also match the spaceship operator (<=>). I writed the following regular expression:
`([^<>!]*)([<>!]=[>]|[<>=])([^=]*)`
Can you add this to your answer to others to find the complete expression?

Comment: I tested the `(\w+)([<>]=?|!?=)(\w+)` expression on the same `3!=2` logical expression, but it not worked.

Comment: `([^<>!]*)([<>!]=[>]|[<>=])([^=]*)` isn't going to work properly. It will also match such operators as `>=>` and `!=>`.

Comment: @kukko Wait, maybe it requires escaping? Try `\\w` instead of `\w`.

Comment: @kukko What do you mean by "not working"? What does it say?

Answer (score 1):

The `.*` is eating the `!`. Make the `.*` specific to the operators you don't want it to match. I think:

```
([^!<>=]+)(<|>|<=|>=|!=|=)(.*)
```

Should do it.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yM5aY8/1

or if you are only work with numbers just use `\d+`.

Demo2: https://regex101.com/r/yM5aY8/2

Answer (score 1):

Instead of only .* in the beginning and end try '\w.*' if the there are digits/variableName on both sides of expression

```
(\w.*)(<|>|<=|>=|=|!=)(\w.*)
```